# Why is my DatePicker (BunifuUI) not showing when clicked on client?

Tags: c#, wpf, datepicker, bunifu

I have an C# WPF application that has the Bunifu datepicker. When I click the datepicker 'dropdown', the calendar will show up. This works for an other client as well. However, I have a client right now that can't click the dropdown. Or at least, nothing happens.. No calendar window will popup.

As I'm not very good in programming I've no idea what it can be. Code is working for me and the other client.

[image: Datepicker WITH calendar]

```
// DateProductivity
// 
this.DateProductivity.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.SeaGreen;
this.DateProductivity.BorderRadius = 0;
this.DateProductivity.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
this.DateProductivity.Format = System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Long;
this.DateProductivity.FormatCustom = null;
this.DateProductivity.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(96, 28);
this.DateProductivity.Name = "DateProductivity";
this.DateProductivity.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(210, 35);
this.DateProductivity.TabIndex = 0;
this.DateProductivity.Value = new System.DateTime(2019, 5, 27, 22, 31, 49, 0);
```

Comment: The two Bunifu.dll files are in the same folder as the .exe file

Comment: Comment this line and check `this.DateProductivity.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(96, 28);` .

Comment: @RaoHammas Will try this soon!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of commenting out this.Dateproductivity didn't work.

However, I replaced the datpicker from the BunifuUI with the regular datepicker. Now it seems to be working.